# JBoss AS: use .xml files in the properties-service.xml

Tags: configuration, jboss, xml, system-properties

The **properties service** (configured in `properties-service.xml`) in JBoss application server lets you specify external `.properties` files that are loaded and can then be accessed as system properties from the deployed applications.

(See here http://community.jboss.org/wiki/PropertiesService for more info...)

Is it also possible to load config files in the `.xml` format instead of `.properties`?

I know it is possible for certain given configs like for example the `mail-service.xml` and the `jboss-log4j.xml`... But they are both loaded directly by JBoss, and not via the properties service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be possible.  The PropertieServices uses the java.util.Properties class, which contains a loadFromXml method.  Perhaps you could extend the properties service?  Here is some additional info:
http://www.webreference.com/programming/Globalize-Web-Applications15_Java6/

Here is some more detailed information on how the SystemProperties service works:
http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r4/html/ch10.html

As you may know, you can use either name=value pairs in a .properties file, or a comma-separated list of URL strings in the service descriptor.

Why do you want to use a .xml file instead of .properties?

Comment: .xml files allow for a more detailed (and hierarchical) organization of properties. And as there are no application specific properties in JBoss, only global ones, a good organization is key to avoid a huge mess in the properties. (Think of a JBoss with some dozen deployed applications...)

Comment: Manually extending/writing property loaders isn't really an option. Accessing properties files on the filesystem from JBoss deployed applications is both messy and ugly.